# ActiveMQ embedded on cluster instance

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, cluster-computing, mule-studio

I'm implementing a project with ActiveMQ embedded in a cluster instance with schema DB shared in MuleSoft 3.5.1.
The broker has been configured with spring bean

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean class="org.apache.activemq.xbean.BrokerFactoryBean"
        id="broker">
        <spring:property value="classpath:testActivemq.xml"
            name="config" />
        <spring:property value="true" name="start" />
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

I have tested the system in local mule server stand alone to simululate cluster.

[image]

The problem is when I make the deploy the first broker, it grabs an exclusive lock on a table to ensure that no other ActiveMQ  broker can access the database at the same time,but the other broker doesn't finish the deploy process and so when I try to undeploy the first broker the server goes in block.
How to resolve my issue?

Comment: rather than undeploying you should be trying to shut down activemq on that instance,and check whether slave can gain the lock or not

Comment: How can I shut down the ActiveMQ on that instance, if ActiveMQ is into the instance? For the shut down the ActiveMQ embedded instance the only way is undeploy the project on the Mule server. Are you agree?

Comment: ok i get it, need to find other way

Comment: I could build a flow to enable the ActiveMQ broker with delay using Quartz component to allow the end of the deploy to the second broker. How does Quartz work in a cluster? Other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is ActiveMQ's built in master-slave functionality. To start multiple brokers in the same VM, you need to point their storage locations to different databases (if using JDBC storage) or filesystem locations (if using KahaDB or LevelDB).

See the following on how to do that:

- JDBC http://activemq.apache.org/jdbc-master-slave.html
- KahaDB http://activemq.apache.org/kahadb.html
- LevelDB http://activemq.apache.org/leveldb-store.html